# Prove the $\operatorname{length}(\alpha) \ge \|v\|$ so that the line segment from $P$ to $Q$ gives the shortest possible path

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $P,Q \in \mathbb{R^3} $ and let $\alpha:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be any parameterized curve with $\alpha(a)=P, \alpha(b)=Q.$ Let $v=Q-P$. Prove the length$(\alpha) \ge \|v\|$, so that the line segment from $P$ to $Q$  gives the shortest possible path.

My Work:

From the Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality

$u\cdot v \le \|u\|\|v\|$

If $u=\alpha'(t)$,

$\alpha'(t)\cdot v \le \|\alpha'(t)\|\|v\|$

Then $\int_a^b\alpha'(t)\cdot v dt\le \int_a^b\|\alpha'(t)\|\|v\|dt$***

I believe we can take the $v$ out as a constant and get the following

$v\int_a^b\alpha'(t) dt = v\ (\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))=v(Q-P)=v\cdot v \le \|v\|\int_a^b\|\alpha'(t)\|dt$***

$\mathrm{Arclength} = s(t)=\int_a^b\|\alpha'(t)\|dt$

$v\cdot v \le \|v\|s(t)$

Since $s(t)$ can be any path, the shortest one is the one taken by $v$ where the two inequality becomes a n equality. But for any other path, it will be longer than the segment from $P$ to $Q$.

I think this makes sense, but I'm not sure. If it is correct, I would like to know how I justify the steps with the *** at the end. Say I was a professor and a student came up to me and I had to judge whether this followed from calculus.

---

Update

$\|v\|=\|Q−P\|=\|\alpha(b)−\alpha(a)\| = \left\|\int_a^b \alpha ' (t)dt\right\| = s(t)$

$\alpha'(t)\cdot v \le \|\alpha'(t)\|\|v\|$

$\alpha'(t)\cdot v \le \|\alpha'(t)\|s(t)$

I believe now we can say that $v$ is the shortest path by the Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

Comment: I suggest you write $||Q - P|| = ||\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)||$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus (so assume $\alpha$ is $C^1$, which it seems like you already are).

Comment: What does $\|u\|=\alpha!(t)$ mean?

Comment: ||$u$|| should be $u$. It is the velocity vector $\alpha ' (t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the equality
$$
\|v\| = \left\|\int_a^b \alpha'(t) \mathrm{d}t\right\|,
$$
and thanks to the triangular inequality for integrals, it follows that
$$
\|v\| \leqslant \int_a^b \left\|\alpha'(t)\right\|\mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{length}(\alpha).
$$